# Dirty way to alter table to change column type in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the situation I have a big table(a few millions of records)
I need to update one column data type from **varchar (250)** to **text**. However here is the trick, there are multiple views created based on this table, these views are also used in a few other views and a few procedures, so deleting cascade and just simply recreating it is not an option.
**Is there any other tricky/dirty way to change it?**

Comment: I just went through something similar a couple of weeks ago.  I could not find any quick/dirty way to accomplish this, but I did use this as an opportunity to get all the code/DDL under git.  I found that pulling definitions from pg_views and pg_proc was much cleaner than the UI that I use.  Sorry this is not really an answer.

Comment: @MikeOrganek - This is a very reasonable answer. I cannot imagine working on a non-trivial Postgres project without code version control.

Comment: Why is delete cascade "not an option"? It's the *only* option. Write a script to do the whole process, test it in non-prod then pick a time and pull the trigger. If your source code is not under source control, your situation is grave.

Comment: @klin You would be surprised how many development teams do not version the DDL in git/scm.

Comment: @TheImpaler you would be surprised but the thing is this code is legacy people start writing it more than 15 years ago, and yes there is no normal repo for it where I can see all dependencies. Plus its multiple schemas where code should be the same but it is not

Comment: @Bohemian this is exactly a case there is no source control, multiple schemas, and legacy code written ages ago :(  That's why I am looking at some dirty way to do it

Comment: Your first move should be to get all the source from the catalog and into GitHub. Have a look at liquibase or flyway to automate schema changes (I've used both). Get a stable repeatable process going for releasing schema/plsql/view changes. You can rescue your situation, but do everything according to best practices  from here on.

Answer (score 1):

Main questions:

1. How long can you carry out maintenance.
2. How much space does this table take up? And how much free space is left on the tablespace?

--to get a list of dependent FUCTIONS/PROCEDURES use something like this:

```
SELECT n.nspname, p.proname, p.prosrc
FROM pg_proc p 
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace 
WHERE p.prosrc ilike '%Table_xxx%';
```

--you can also check object dependency in pgAdmin

--to get a list of dependent VIEWS use something like this:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, pg_get_viewdef(table_schema||'.'||table_name, true)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_type = 'VIEW'
AND pg_get_viewdef(table_schema||'.'||table_name, true) ilike '%Table_xxx%';
```

--so now you have a list of dependent objects. you can test your updates.

--Don`t forget about DCL (you need to test it or just use pgAdmin):

```
SELECT 'GRANT '||privilege_type||' ON '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' TO '||grantee||';'
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='Table_xxx';
```

--next step. (if you have enough maintenance time:)

--in SINNGLE TRANSACTION:

--drop dependent objects

--change column type

ALTER TABLE Table_xxx ALTER COLUMN c_xxx TYPE text;

--recreate dependent objects

--restore DCL

--next step. (if you need to modify a lot of columns and you have enought space and time) you can:

--create temporary transformed table:

--stop your ETL-processes.

--in SINNGLE TRANSACTION:

--make transformations:

-- drop dependent objects

CREATE TABLE Table_xxx_tmp AS
SELECT c_1, c_xxx::text, c_n FROM Table_xxx;

-- replace tables:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE Table_xxx rename to Table_xxx_old;
ALTER TABLE TABLE Table_xxx_tmp rename to Table_xxx;
```

--recreate dependent objects (+triggers etc)

--4th restore DCL

--start your ETL-processes.

--but the MAIN THING here: think with your head.